# Python Declare Variables in Function Call?

Tags: python, function, variables

Sorry if this has already been asked, I'm not sure exactly how to describe my question in a sentence anyway. I'm doing some work for my bioinformatics course, and I've begun to see variables declared when functions are called, instead of just passing the argument (see line 5 below).

```
def sobelFilter(pixmap):
  matrix = array([[-1, 0, 1],
                  [-2, 0, 2],
                  [-1, 0, 1]])
  grey = pixmap.mean(axis=2) #<---here
  edgeX = convolveMatrix2D(grey, matrix)
  edgeY = convolveMatrix2D(grey, matrix.T)
  pixmap2 = sqrt(edgeX * edgeX + edgeY * edgeY)
  normalisePixmap(pixmap2)
  return pixmap2
```

What is the purpose of `grey = pixmap.mean(axis=2)` when `axis` is never used again? Why not just say `grey = pixmap.mean(2)`?

If it's necessary for my question, this is just code we were given to use, not written by myself. Pixmap refers to this code:

```
def imageToPixmapRGB(img):
    img2 = img.convert("RGB")
    w,h = img2.size
    data = img2.getdata()
    pixmap = array(data, float)
    pixmap = pixmap.reshape((h,w,3))
    return pixmap
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a local variable called `axis` being initialized, you are just explicitly stating which parameter of the function you are passing.

You might use this if there are multiple optional parameters in a function:

Example:

```
In [9]: def foo(x=2, y=2):
   ...:     print(x, y)
   ...:

In [10]: foo(y=3)
2 3
```

If I want to change `y`, but leave `x` as default, I must specify when I call the function.

Even when you aren't setting a particular optional parameter however, there is nothing wrong with passing an argument by its keyword.

Comment: Minor note: [PEP8 spacing rules](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations) calls for no spaces around equals signs used when defining default values or passing arguments by keyword, partially to disambiguate from variable assignment (which does use spaces).

Answer (score 1):

This looks a bit like the variable assignment syntax because of the `=`, but it is actually a very different feature:

When you call functions, you can specify which variables to set to what using the "keyword argument" syntax. This allows you to set specific parameters by name:

```
some_func(arg1, arg2, arg5=None)
```

This is very useful with default arguments:

```
def x(a, b, c=None, d=None):
    pass
```

If you wanted to set `d` with the normal syntax, you would have to specify an argument for `c` too.

```
x(1, 2, None, "hi")
```

Using the keyword argument syntax, you can omit this:

```
x(1, 2, d="hi")
```

Keyword arguments are often, like in this case, also used to make the purpose of a parameter clear to the reader. If you see:

```
pixmap.mean(2)
```

It is not immediately clear what the `2` meas. However, if you see

```
pixmap.mean(axis=2)
```

you immediately know what `2` refers to and why it's there

Also see [this section of the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments)

Comment: Hadn't thought about its purpose in making the parameter clear, good observation to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

`pixmap` is a `numpy` array with dimension >= 2. You can test this by printing `pixmap.ndim`.

The line you refer to is calculating the `mean` of an array *along an axis*. In other words, `axis` is an *argument* of the `mean` method. See `numpy.mean` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) for more details.

You are right in that the `axis` parameter may be omitted, i.e. `arr.mean(2)` is equivalent to `arr.mean(axis=2)`. Most likely it was explicitly stated for clarity.